# How to make protractor run on chrome

Tags: angular, protractor, automated-tests

I have a problem with protractor, I run a test on Firefox and work well, but when I change de configuration to run on chrome the test is freeze. My test page is load, but the automated test doing nothing.

Here is my conf:

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  allScriptsTimeout: 200000000,


  capabilities: {
    //  'browserName': 'firefox'
     'browserName': 'chrome'
  },


  framework: 'jasmine2',
  directConnect: true,

  getPageTimeout: 1000000000,

  specs: [ 

  'testLoginFunc.js'

    ],
}
```

And here is my test:

```
describe('WebApp-Test : test the login component ->', function() {

  //exoired pass: 4904 id: 0QhK2S5f9llF
  // pass: 9211 id: fOTxM7cYcJmk

  beforeEach (function () {
    // browser.restart(); //loads the page
    browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

    // Set the browser page seize
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(widthDesktop, heightDesktop);
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.driver.get('https://share.tracemytrack.com/webapp');
  });


  it('test the login functionality when the session is expired', function() {
    console.log("\nTEST_LOGIN: test the login functionality when the session is expired");
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var sessionFieldVisibile = element(by.css('#sessionfield'));
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(sessionFieldVisibile), 11000);
    element(by.css('#sessionfield')).sendKeys('0QhK2S5f9llF');
    var loginButtonSess = element(by.buttonText('Next'));
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(loginButtonSess), 12000);
    loginButtonSess.click();

    element(by.css('#passwordfield')).sendKeys('4904');
    var loginButtonPass = element(by.buttonText('Next'));
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(loginButtonPass), 13000);
    loginButtonPass.click();
    browser.sleep(6000);



    //Check if the message appears.
    expect(element(by.css('strong')).getText()).toBe('Wrong Password!');
    browser.restart();
  });
});
```

In this test i tried to make a login, and on firefox it works, but in chrome the username work well, but when it tries to insert the password, the test is freeze

Comment: check the compatibility of chromedriver and chrome browser. Refer http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: @NitinSahu ty :) I found the error and yep... the chromedriver what I used is an old version :)